# Fixing a RewriteRule that adds two extra slashes

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect web requests from `example.org` to `www.example.org`. I think I have the right rule, but it is adding two extra forward slashes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

The above would take me from `example.org` to `www.example.org//`

Is there a way to strip those trailing slashes? I tried the following variant, which strips those slashes but causes a redirect loop:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

How might I solve this?

Comment: You don't want to add a redirect from the `//` to `/`, that'll slow down every access to your site and potentially mess with your SEO. Fix the actual problem (generating the `//` URL in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `RewriteBase /` right after `RewriteEngine on`.

If that doesn't do it, change your rule to `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]` so you don't capture the initial `/`.

Comment: I get the error `RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files` for the first solution, but the second solution appears to work properly in Chrome, Safari and Firefox (after clearing cache). Thanks!